# how to use a component from a form into other forms in c#

Tags: c#, xmpp

I have a Xmpp client connection named x in my Form1.I want to use that in other Form of the project.

i have 7 Forms.But i have defined the connection in Form1 only.

how can i use that in other Form..

Following is connection i defined in Form1

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
       XmppClientConnection x;
```

When i click a button on Form1 it opens Form2.I also defined to use x in Form2 using:

```
//form2 load
        public static string sendtext = "";
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sendtext = textBox1.Text;
        Form2 form = new Form2(x);
        form.Show(); 

    }
```

But this is working out.

Answer (score 0):

Move the instantiation of `x` out of Form1 to, say, your Program or Application object. Then pass a reference to the original object to each form. This is what you're already doing with Form1 and Form2, you just need to generalize it a bit more and pass that same reference to each form.

Comment: i created new connection if x is null.

    if(x==null)
    {
     x= new XmppClientConnection();
    }
 
    Form2 form = new Form2(x);
    form.Show();

Comment: So you're doing the same thing with Form3 through Form7 ? That will certainly work and is really the same thing as what I suggested.